# How to pass image (from image URL) to tensorflow tf.fromPixels method

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

Trying to pass a Image (from url) into the `tf.fromPixels` method as per my code below but getting this error:

```
Error: pixels passed to tf.browser.fromPixels() must be either an HTMLVideoElement, HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, ImageData in browser, or OffscreenCanvas, ImageData in webworker or {data: Uint32 Array, width: number, height: number}, but was Image
```

Code:

```
const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs");
require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node")
const { Image } = require("canvas");


async function load() {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = 'https://www.google.com/favicon.ico';
  img.onload = () => {
    const output = tf.browser.fromPixels(img);
  }
}

load();
```

How to get image URL into one of the acceptable formats (e.g HTMLImageElement) so tensorflow can read it? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a `NodeJS` project?

In that case, don't import both `tfjs` and `tfjs-node`, import just `tfjs-node`

And `tf.browser.*` methods are not available in NodeJS - like the namespace indicates, they are browser-only as they rely on browser itself to decode image data and read pixels

But there are other methods available for `NodeJS` under `tf.node.*` namespace

For example, you can use this to load image from URL even without `Canvas`, just need a `fetch` (e.g. `node-fetch` or something similar)

```js
const res = await fetch(url);
const buffer = res && res.ok ? await res.buffer() : null;
const tensor = tf.tidy(() => {
  const decode = tf.node.decodeImage(buffer, 3);
  const expand = tf.expandDims(decode, 0);
  return expand;
});
```